# How can I manipulate JSON data in dart / flutter for use in a listview

Tags: flutter, dart

### **Background**

I have the following JSON data that is being remotely retrieved via an async request, that I'm trying to build a list view out of in Flutter.

As you can see the first item is 'logged in' which is totally different from all the other items

I'm having a lot of trouble in flutter when trying to build a list view out of the data (I'm a total flutter noob -->  This is day 0).

```
[
  {
    "loggedin": "0"
  }, 
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "excerpt": "",
    "thumb": "Image 1.jpg",
    "threadid": "1",
    "fid": "1",
    "commentcount": "1",
    "postdate": 1
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Title 2",
    "excerpt": "",
    "thumb": "Image 2.jpg",
    "threadid": "2",
    "fid": "2",
    "commentcount": "2",
    "postdate": 2
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "title": "Title 3",
    "excerpt": "",
    "thumb": "Image3.jpg",
    "threadid": "3",
    "fid": "3",
    "commentcount": "3",
    "postdate": 3
}
]
```

### **My Conceptual Solution**

I was thinking of stripping out the first item logged in and forming a whole new Json array with just Items 1-3

### **My Question**

Is it possible to iterate through the decoded json data and form a new array?

I can successfully access an individual item in my list as follows:

```
  _map = json.decode(response.body)[1];
```

However when I try to iterate through my list it fails

```
      final decoded = json.decode(response.body) as dynamic;
              decoded.forEach((key, value) {
                if (key != "loggedin") {
                  debugPrint('hi');
                }
              });
```

If I try to iterate through just one of the items then it does work:

```
      final decoded = json.decode(response.body)[1] as dynamic;
      decoded.forEach((key, value) {
        debugPrint(key+': '+value);
      });
```

I needed to iterate through my list as a starting point to pick out the items I want to remove from my final list (basically the item with a key of "loggedin", but I'm failing miserably here

### **Alternatives**

I realize the very concept of my approach is most likely flawed or tedious.  If any other alternative approach to achieve my goal seems better I'm all ears! :)

Comment: @Pythony When I try to iterate the entire list I'm getting this error: type '(dynamic,dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error's happening because your data is a list of maps but in the list iterator you are passing a function with two parameters, which works for a map.

You should do it like this -

```
final decoded = json.decode(response.body) as dynamic;
              decoded.forEach((data) {
                //data is a Map
              });
```

You can access the individual keys like this - `data["loggedin"]`

To check whether it contains 'loggedin', you can do `data.containsKey("loggedin")`

For a list, the function in the forEach takes one Argument which is a list item, and for a Map it takes two, a key and its corresponding value.

Comment: this is working great!  As a follow-up may I ask: How would you remove that first loggedin item and return either a list or a map with all the remaining data intact without redefining everything allover again?

Comment: Happy it helped! You can remove the first item in the list with this decoded.removeAt(0);

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a Model class with the below fields:

- id
- title
- excerpt
- thumb
- threadid
- fid
- commentcount
- postdate
- **loggedin**

Now, for the first item, all fields will be null except `loggedin` and for other items `loggedin` will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Convert response to `List<Map>`, iterate through list, ignore item that contains keys `loggedin`

```
    final List<Map> list = json.decode(response.body);
    list.forEach((element) { 
      if(!element.containsKey("loggedin")){
        //Here element is map of your required item
        //You can convert it to your required model
      }
    });
```